# How can i extract the info between " " ? C#

Tags: c#, serial-port, buffer

Can anyone tell me how to extract the following info to a variable in a simple way from this output.

Output:

```
AT+CMGL="ALL"
+CMGL: 0,"REC READ","+40728072005",,"12/06/29,13:04:26+12"
password,1,ON
```

i want to extract from some info from the above output like below into variables:

```
msisdn="+40728072005"
passwd="password"
itemno="1"
command="ON"
```

--

```
    string split = ",";
    string[] substrings = Regex.Split(buff, split);
    foreach (string match in substrings)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("'{0}'", match);
    }
```

image -> [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zl6Nj.png

Is there a way to exclude the unwanted output from the start? 
like a grep -v, i am not that familiar with C#.

So far i got to this point:

```
    string split = ",";
    string split1 = "\"";
    string split2 = "OK";
    string[] substrings = Regex.Split(buff, split);
    string[] substrings1 = Regex.Split(substrings[2], split1);
    Console.WriteLine(substrings1[1]);
    string[] substrings2 = Regex.Split(substrings[5], split1);

    Console.WriteLine(substrings2[1]);
    Console.WriteLine(substrings[6]);
    string[] substrings3 = Regex.Split(substrings[7], split2);
    Console.WriteLine(substrings3[0]);
```

still, this is done by splitting the string because i know the message format.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: You could look for existing CSV parsers. The framework itself doesn't contain one, but I'm sure there are plenty of open source ones.

Comment: i tried regex, but with no success. is it a easier way to split the text and retrieve just the data i need ?

Comment: look out for a regex tutorial - for example: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228595%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Comment: Depends on how you define "easier way". In code, there is no easier way than a single regex. In brain however... show the regex which you tried with no success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this demo, put it in a Main method of a console application (it uses Regex so you have to add line "using System.Text.RegularExpressions;"):

```
        string input = "AT+CMGL=\"ALL\"\n+CMGL: 0,\"REC READ\",\"+40728072005\",,\"12/06/29,13:04:26+12\"\npassword,1,ON";
        var matches = Regex.Matches(
            input,
            @"\""(?<msisdn>\+\d*)\"",.*,\""(?<date>\d{2}\/\d{2}/\d{2},\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}\+\d{2})\"".*\n+(?<passwd>[^,]*),(?<itemno>\d*),(?<command>\w*)"
            , RegexOptions.Multiline);

        foreach (Match m in matches)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(m.Groups["msisdn"].Value);
            Console.WriteLine(m.Groups["date"].Value);
            Console.WriteLine(m.Groups["passwd"].Value);
            Console.WriteLine(m.Groups["itemno"].Value);
            Console.WriteLine(m.Groups["command"].Value);
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
```

Basically, regular expression searches for a defined pattern inside text.
Meaning of the expression:

\"" - that's how a quote sign is defined, it is escaped with backslash and written twice so it doesn't cause compiler error.

(?+\d*) - generally, bracketed expression means that you are capturing a group, this here is a named group and it's name is specified by ?, this group is going to capture string that begins with + sign (it is escaped by backslash) followed by numbers which are represented by backslash and letter "d" ("d" comes from "digit"). Backslash is used as an escape character for characters with special meaning. Asterisk * means that character that comes before it can occur 0 or more times.

\"" - quote, this is closing quote for "msisdn" number.

, - means comma.

.* - dot means any character, and asterisk that follows it means that any character can occur 0 or more times.

(?\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{2},\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}+\d{2}) - named group that captures date, expression \d{2} has \d which means digit and {2} which tells regex engine that digit shoud occur two times, then comes / - it means forwardslash (it is escaped by a backslash). Afterwards come digits separated by colons and in the end plus sign and two digits after it, that's how the date is extracted.

\n+ - \n means newline, + is a quantifier which means that newline appears one or more times.

(?[^,]*) - is a named group that captures password part, [^,] means that any character except comma should be captured, square brackets mean range of characters, ^ means negation, asterisk means that character can occur 0 or more times.

(?\d*) - is a named group that captures numbers as defined by \d*

(?\w*) - is a named group that captures word characters (letters, digits, and underscores)

Comment: Hi, it returns 5 blank lines, the output contains also some empty lines and OK at the end, like in here: http://i.stack.imgur.com/zl6Nj.png

Comment: Hi, I changed it, you can try it now

Comment: I'm glad to help, is it giving you the output that you needed? I also changed Singleline to Multiline mode so that it returns all occurances of such pattern (not only first one that was found).

Comment: Ivan can you please help me with another REGEX or better exaplain me how is this one done so i can modify it and make another one :D.

Comment: Sure, I'll add more comments to the answer. Best thing would be to go through one of the tutorials about regular expressions

Comment: thanks Ivan, i got a hold of what you did there and modified for the other regex :) thanks a lot again.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13236/discussion-between-alexis-cimpu-and-ivan-83)

Comment: is it possible to add another group in the regex that can appear or not.. depends on the message

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you've got a fixed number of comma-separated values, so the position defines the meaning of the particular value. I'd remove everything before the equality sign, then split by commas and treat the needed values separately.